# I am no able to split into input & output my dataset in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I read the dataset from txt file (supppose to be "values") and the I try to split into X, y in order to start applying ML.

```
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10])
# split into input and output values
X, y = values[:,:-1], values[:,-1]
# split into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.67)
```

It pops up an error saying: `too many indices for array`. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: sorry @Prune, Im new here. I already updated my question. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @JesúsPérez Try https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: values[:,:-1] ,  this reads as take everything from the first dimension, and everything but the last from the second dimension.   Your input is only 1-dimensional so that would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values[:,:-1]` expression rises an error, did you mean to assign reverse of the `values` array to **X** and `values` to `y`? If so, you should write as following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10])
# split into input and output values
X, y = values[::-1], values
# split into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.67)
```